# Openldap Acl update error

Tags: openldap

I was trying to modify the current ACL rule in openldap by removing the current rule and updating it with  a new one via new acl.ldif file using the below command.

```
ldapmodify -xWD cn=admin,cn=config -f acl.ldif
```

But I am getting below error while executing it.

```
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Object class violation (65)
        additional info: attribute 'olcOverlay' not allowed
```

This is my current olcdatabase file.

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=test,dc=test1,dc=com
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymou
 s auth by dn="ou=admin,dc=test,dc=test1,dc=com" write by * read
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=test,dc=test1,dc=com" w
 rite by * read
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=test,dc=test1,dc=com
olcRootPW:: e1Nb01QN3Mrckk=
olcDbCheckpoint: 512 30
olcDbConfig: {0}set_cachesize 0 2097152 0
olcDbConfig: {1}set_lk_max_objects 1500
olcDbConfig: {2}set_lk_max_locks 1500
olcDbConfig: {3}set_lk_max_lockers 1500
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN,entryUUID eq
structuralObjectClass: olcHdbConfig
entryUUID: 372c8246-a1b5-1031-9131-6b135443c1be
creatorsName: cn=admin,cn=config
createTimestamp: 20121003144902Z
entryCSN: 20121003144902.063840Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20121003144902Z
olcOverlay: syncprov
olcSpCheckPoint: 50 10
olcSpSessionlog: 100
```

And below provided is my acl.ldif file.

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}
-
# Then add a new ACL at position {0}.
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by dn="ou=Users,dc=test,dc=test1,dc=com" write by * read
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current database config is likely invalid. Unless you've done something atypical to your schema, the use of the `olcOverlay` attribute is not provided for by any of the objectClasses in your config entry. The error message isn't about what you're trying to do, but instead about what you've already done.

This is a more common sort of structure:

```
$ ldapsearch -b olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config objectClass @olcSyncProvConfig
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig

dn: olcOverlay={0}syncprov,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: {0}syncprov
olcSpCheckpoint: 100 10
olcSpSessionlog: 100

dn: olcOverlay={1}memberof,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcMemberOf
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
olcOverlay: {1}memberof

# find /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config/olcOverlay={0}syncprov.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=module{0}.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}hdb
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}hdb/olcOverlay={0}syncprov.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={7}openssh-lpk.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={0}core.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={3}rfc2307bis.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={8}sudo.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={2}inetorgperson.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={4}misc.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={6}kerberos.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={5}dhcp.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={1}cosine.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb/olcOverlay={1}memberof.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb/olcOverlay={0}syncprov.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={-1}frontend.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif
```